# Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root error

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I am trying to upload my project to Vercel for hosting, but halfway through I got this error as shown below:

```
Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
at Object.findPagesDir (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:39:15)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:92:77
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:58:29)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

I do not encounter any of these errors when I am running my project on the local host, does anyone know how to fix this issue?
The image shown below is my file directory:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply creating that folder, like the message asked you to?

Comment: you add project via github?

Comment: @Aaqu yes i put my project to github and from vercel i import the project from github

Comment: @CBroe i dont have folder that starts with /vercel

Comment: @Shadowwalker locally you run build and start?

Comment: Git cannot store empty directories. So if your `pages` directory contain no files you will get this error when deploying to Vercel from a git repo. Either create a file in that folder (eg. `.ingore_me`) or write a script to automatically create that folder if it doesn't exist.